# How to add value to the navigation tab created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an extra navigation tab using JavaScript.  It kinda works but not the way I want it.  So the idea is to add an extra navigation tab with the link leading to another page.  However, when I create the tab 1) it comes without the a:hover properties (all other tabs have it) and 2) I don't know how to assign a value to it (link to another webpage). Here is my code:
HTML5

```
  <nav>
    <ul id="topnav">
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li> &nbsp; 
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li> &nbsp;
      <li><a href="Order.html">Order</a></li> &nbsp;       
      <!-- Location.html -->  <!-- Load dynamically -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
var list = document.getElementById("topnav");
var contact = document.createElement("li");
list.appendChild(contact);
contact.innerHTML = "Location";
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

 li {
    display: inline;
 }

 a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

 a:hover {
    background-color: #798585;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: You almost have it. You’re already creating the `<li>` correctly. Now create the `<a>`. Or just clone the element: `const contact = list.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);` and set `href` and `textContent` to its `firstElementChild`.

Comment: I red your comment, looked at my code and realized I've had too much copy/pasting today.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an element `a` and then append it to the list

```
var list = document.getElementById("topnav");
var contact = document.createElement("li");
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute("href","somelink.html")
a.textContent="Location"
contact.append(a)
list.append(contact)
```

Comment: @user4642212 Thanks for the feedback it's just one of them days, it's all fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the anchor in the innerHTML of the li element you created:

```js
contact.innerHTML = "<a href=\"urlofyourpage\">Location</a>";
```